# how to remove/edit old attachments using google classroom API

Tags: google-classroom

using the google classroom api i am able to modify attachments
and everytime i call the method

```
courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.modifyAttachments
```

but the attachments just concatenate to the previously attached files.

my question is how can i remove an attachment that i accidently added or that i want to replace?
just like the classroom UI enables you to remove an attachment after you added it

[Google classroom UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy58w.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no feature available to remove attachments with Google Classroom API . This is a product limitation for the API and can be promoted for future development [1].  Your idea will then be available for other members of the community to browse and vote on. Depending on the business impact Google product engineers typically roll out into production.

[1] https://developers.google.com/classroom/support#missing_features